# SQL table - Insert and Deletes time out, select OK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 where all tables seem to be functioning normally except for one table.

In this table, I can't delete a row or insert a row because it goes for over 30 min and times out.

My insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[brokenTable] ([Change], [Date], [ProdId], [IntCol]) 
VALUES ('test', getdate(), null, '99999')
```

However, I can select. Selecting top 200,000 takes 33 seconds. There are only ~260,000 rows in the table. There are five columns(one int primary key, one date, another int columns, and 2 varchar columns.)

This table used to work fine and be quick, I have made no structure changes at all.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might have happened, and how to fix it?

Comment: Probably an open transaction holding a lock. Do the `INSERT` in one window in SSMS whilst it is blocked go to another query window in SSMS and look in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see what is blocking it.

Comment: Does your table have any indexes?

Comment: @MartinSmith I did select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks and 15 rows come up, however i'm not sure exactly how to read this..  Here are the wait_type, do any look suspect?
XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT
REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH
BROKER_EVENTHANDLER
BROKER_TRANSMITTER
LAZYWRITER_SLEEP
KSOURCE_WAKEUP
BROKER_TO_FLUSH
LCK_M_IX
LOGMGR_QUEUE
CHECKPOINT_QUEUE
XE_TIMER_EVENT
ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE
BROKER_TRANSMITTER
FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT
SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP

Comment: @Limey 3 of the columns have a index on them.

Comment: `LCK_M_IX` seems suspect. You can filter by `session_id` of the blocked transaction to be sure you are looking at the right thing. In your window doing the insert this will be shown at the bottom in the status bar or just run `SELECT @@SPID` in that connection first.

Comment: You can find out exactly which SPID is blocking you if you run sp_who2 [SPID of your insert statement] in another window while you're trying to insert.  There is a column called BlkBy which gives you the spid blocking you.  To get the spid of your request, look for the number in parentheses in your SSMS window.

Comment: Hmm, yes, the LCK_M_IX does go away if i cancel the insert and rerun the select on sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks. any idea what could cause it? i'm off to google right now to see if i can dig anything up

Comment: Have the been deleting a large amount of rows lately?  maybe you need to reindex.

Comment: @user1308743 - What is `blocking_session_id`? You can plug that into `sys.dm_exec_sessions` or `sys.dm_exec_connections` to get more details of the offending session. Do you have any open windows in SSMS that you yourself might have left an open transaction in?

Comment: @Zhenny nothing seems to be returned when i used the SPID of the insert query window.

Comment: @MartinSmith i found the blocking session. how do I end that session?

Comment: @user1308743 Check to see what is causing the session first via what Martin said.  If it's ok to end it, just type "kill [session #]".

Comment: @user1308743 - [You can use this query to see the last SQL run by that session first](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1799/identify-last-statement-run-for-a-specific-sql-server-session/) before killing it. Killing will roll back any work done by that transaction.

Comment: If [IntCol] is, as expected, and integer column, don't put single quotes around the number...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To people of the future who may have the same problem.

I thought the query was going very slow, this was not the case. It was being locked by another session. If you follow Martin Smith's comments, he helped me find which one to fix it.

First, I ran

```
select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
```

while running a query that would not finish, and again while not running it, to find a LCK_M_IX. I used the Session Id from that row, and matched it with the row from

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

and found the offending session that was blocking my query!

Since I knew this was a safe session to end, i ended it with

```
Kill [sessionId]
```